# In AngularJS can I use the ng-model and the ng-bind only in the view without involving the use of a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I am pretty new to AngularJS and I found this example related to the **ng-model** and **ng-bind** directives:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<page:angular-template>

    <jsp:attribute name="title">
        AngularJS ng-bind ng-model
    </jsp:attribute>

    <jsp:body>                  

    <div ng-app>

    <h1>AngularJS ng-bind ng-model</h1>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
            <td><b>Username:</b></td> <td><input type="text" ng-model="username"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Password:</b></td> <td><input type="text" ng-model="passwords"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><b>authorization:</b></td>  <td><input type="text" ng-model="authorization"/> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div> 

    Hi {{ username }} welcome to Java Spring MVC Integrated with AngularJS by Google and HTML5<br/>
    You password is {{ passwords }} <br/>
    and login as <span ng-bind="authorization"></span> <br/>
    </div>


    </jsp:body>
</page:angular-template>
```

So basically it seems to me that it only shows a form and that each **input** element is related to a **model property** by the **ng-model** attribute.

Then, in the same page, I can retrieve the values of these model property by for example an AngularJS expression like **{{ username }}** or using the **ng-bind** directive. So for example:

```
<span ng-bind="authorization">
```

it means that in this span it should show the value inserted in the input tag having **ng-model="authorization"**

Is it my reasoning correct?

My doubt is: in using AngularJS, can I avoid going thru a controller? I have alredy seen how to put these values inside a property of the **$scope** service.

For example, the input tag **ng-model** is a specific property of the **$scope** service (that in this way is associating a view to a controller).

Can I avoid going thru a controller?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, yes you are right and you did got it well.

That's the magic of Angular. DOM-wise you have a "minimal App" without even using a Controller.

By that you can make the DOM to show the data you are typing.

Of course in order to process it he data or do something with them you will need to have a controller,  but you could even set a value to something without going thru the controller by using `ng-init` and set the `authorization` variable to whatever you want.

```
<div ng-init="authorization='yeah'"></div>
```

[ng-init doc](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp)

So, YES, you can use angular that way without a controller.

(Hope I got your question..)

Comment: The Italian is cute, but the OP understands English, which is preferred on this website. Also how, can we access the model objects, if not through a controller?

Comment: Sorry, u are right, I'll fix it. I guess he is asking if he can read those variables without the controller. To me is feasible.